# Moving back and forth on multiple panels

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel (named main panel) inside which i have adjusted 3 panels (namely panel1, panel2 and panel3 respectively) with the help of document outline windows so that they all are placed at same location, one over another but not inside each other. When the form is loaded, only panel 1 is visible, rest panel 2 and panel 3 are hidden, now on clicking button named button1 inside panel 1, it opens panel2 and hides panel 1. similarly on clicking button named button2 inside panel2, it opens panel3 and hides panel2. and finally, when i click button3 or button 4 or button5 (these 3 are inside panel3) inside panel3, they open a new form. Now the problem is i have managed to move forth by clicking all these buttons(or by capturing keystrokes) starting from panel1 but don't know how to move back to previous panel like from panel3 to panel 2 and from panel2 to panel1 using keystrokes. Please suggest me a way to achieve this using escape key .

```
 public partial class directionform : Form
 {
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
 {
     switch (keyData)
     {
         
         case Keys.I:
             // Simulate clicks on button1.
             //  button1.PerformClick();
             buttonwithcue1.PerformClick();
             break;
         case Keys.U:
             // Simulates clic on button2.
             button2.PerformClick();
             break;
         case Keys.L:
             buttonwithcue2.PerformClick();
             return true;
         //e.Handled = true;
         // break;           
         case Keys.C:
             buttonwithcue3.PerformClick();
             return true;
         //e.Handled = true;
         // break;   
         case Keys.A:
             buttonwithcue4.PerformClick();
             return true;
         //e.Handled = true;
         // break;   
         case Keys.D:
             buttonwithcue5.PerformClick();
             return true;
         //e.Handled = true;
         // break;   
         default:
             break;
   if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
     {
         **// how to move back on pressing escape key** 
     }
     return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
     }
private void directionform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     panel5.Hide();
     panel6.Hide();
        
 }
private void buttonwithcue1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     panel1.Hide();
     panel2.Show();
  }
   private void buttonwithcue2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     panel2.Hide();       
     panel3.Show();
    
 }
  // all three below buttons belong to panel 3 (last panel ) 
         private void buttonwithcue3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {           
     panel3.Hide();          
   // go to next form  
 }
 private void buttonwithcue4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {           
     panel3.Hide();           
  // go to next form  
 }
 private void buttonwithcue5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    panel3.Hide();         
  // go to next form  
 }
```

Comment: You will need to reformulate the problem, as the indexed panels are not really intuitive and people will be less motivated to read the description over and over again. Some kind of visual mapping might be helpful.

Comment: This post is very hard to read. You should add at the very least a few line breaks..

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a stack of the order the panels are selected.

Panel1 (P1) is the current panel.

e.g. user selects Panel2, then the current panel P1 is added to the stack.

user selects Panel4, then the current panel P2 is added to the stack.

Panel4 is the current panel.

user presses the escape key, the panel at the top of the stack P2 is popped and becomes the current panel.